# Are HPP_POST_RESPONSE AND MERCHANT_RESPONSE_URL mutually exclusive?

Tags: global-payments-api

We are reviewing how we implement our global payment solution. Currently we are using HPP and message handlers to capture the response from global payment. This works fine apart from some edge cases which are rare. Is it possible to use both the HPP_Response_Url and the Merchant_Response_Url to capture the responses. Are they mutually exclusive.

Regards

Following is our hpp

```
<form action="https://pay.sandbox.realexpayments.com/pay" method="POST" target="iframe">
        <input type="hidden" name="TIMESTAMP" value="20221122112307">
        <input type="hidden" name="MERCHANT_ID" value="XXX">
        <input type="hidden" name="ACCOUNT" value="internet">
        <input type="hidden" name="ORDER_ID" value="N3qsk4kYRZihmPrTXWYS6g">
        <input type="hidden" name="AMOUNT" value="4">
        <input type="hidden" name="CURRENCY" value="EUR">
        <input type="hidden" name="AUTO_SETTLE_FLAG" value="1">
        <input type="hidden" name="HPP_VERSION" value="2">

        <input type="hidden" name="HPP_CUSTOMER_COUNTRY" value="DE">
        <input type="hidden" name="HPP_CUSTOMER_FIRSTNAME" value="James">
        <input type="hidden" name="HPP_CUSTOMER_LASTNAME" value="Mason">
        <input type="hidden" name="MERCHANT_RESPONSE_URL" value="https://localhost:44369/api/payment/processresponse">
        <input type="hidden" name="HPP_TX_STATUS_URL" value="https://localhost:44369/api/payment/processresponse">
        <input type="hidden" name="HPP_POST_RESPONSE" value="https://localhost:44369/api/payment/processresponse">
        <!-- APMs Mandatory Fields -->
        <input type="hidden" name="SHA1HASH" value="edfd9ff20b616e6e5c3fb195bbf51288390e50e6">
        <input type="submit" value="Click To Pay">
    </form>
```